# Join query results with different WHERE conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to combine these two queries into one? Right now, I have 2 separate queries that I run which show me:

1. UserName and how many Issues they Opened
2. UserName and how many Issues they Closed

**Open Issues:**

```
SELECT FirstName +' ' + LastName AS 'UserName', COUNT(u.UserID) AS IssuesOpened
FROM Users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN Issues i ON i.CreatedByUserID = u.UserID
WHERE i.DateCreated BETWEEN '06/30/2012 23:59:59' AND '07/01/2013 00:00:01'
GROUP BY LastName, FirstName
```

Results look lke this:

```
UserName | IssuesOpened
-----------------------
User 1      10
User 2      8
User 3      55
```

**Closed Issues:**

```
SELECT FirstName +' ' + LastName AS 'UserName', COUNT(u.UserID) AS IssuesClosed
FROM Users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN Issues i ON i.ResolvedByUserID = u.UserID
WHERE ResolvedDate BETWEEN '06/30/2012 23:59:59' AND '07/01/2013 00:00:01'
GROUP BY LastName, FirstName
```

Results look lke this:

```
UserName | IssuesClosed
-----------------------
User 1      8
User 2      2
User 3      40
```

I'd like to join these two queries to get this:

```
UserName | IssuesOpened | IssuesClosed
--------------------------------------
User 1      10              8
User 2      8               2
User 3      55              40
```

I tried something ugly, like this:

```
SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS UserName,
    (SELECT COUNT(u.UserID)
    FROM Users u
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Issues i ON i.ResolvedByUserID = u.UserID
    WHERE ResolvedDate BETWEEN '06/30/2012 23:59:59' AND '07/01/2013 00:00:01')
    AS IssuesClosed,
    (SELECT COUNT(u.UserID)
        FROM Users u
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Issues i ON i.CreatedByUserID = u.UserID
        WHERE i.DateCreated BETWEEN '06/30/2012 23:59:59' AND '07/01/2013 00:00:01')
    AS IssuesOpened
FROM Users u
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
```

But because I removed the `GROUP BY` clause in each subquery, it just returns the total amount of rows.

**UPDATE**

Since I can't load my data into SqlFiddle (both query window and schema window can only hold 8000 characters), I came up with some screenshots of my results vs. sgeddes results:

**My Results** [PhotoBucket Link to larger image:](http://i979.photobucket.com/albums/ae271/robertfah/Code%20Junk/myQueries_zps1ffa5779.png)
[image: My Results]

**sgeddes Results**
[image: SGEDDES Results]

One thing that sticks out to me is if you notice on sgeddes results, the last row, user "Web***" has 449 for "Closed".  This is impossible because that user (Web***) is a placeholder for how we determine how customers open an issue through our website.  This fake user has no access to our system and can't close any ticket.

Answer (score 0):

This should work using `COUNT` with `CASE`:

```
SELECT FirstName +' ' + LastName AS 'UserName', 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN i.DateCreated BETWEEN '06/30/2012 23:59:59' AND '07/01/2013 00:00:01' 
               THEN 1 END) AS IssuesOpened, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN ResolvedDate BETWEEN '06/30/2012 23:59:59' AND '07/01/2013 00:00:01' 
               THEN 1 END) AS IssuesClosed
FROM Users u
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Issues i ON i.CreatedByUserID = u.UserID OR i.ResolvedByUserID = u.UserID
GROUP BY LastName, FirstName
```

This will return all users -- so some may have a count of 0.  If you don't want all, you can add your `WHERE` criteria back using `OR` above the `GROUP BY`.  In doing this, you negate the reason to need an `OUTER JOIN`, so I would change that to an `INNER JOIN` instead.

```
SELECT FirstName +' ' + LastName AS 'UserName', 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN i.DateCreated BETWEEN '06/30/2012 23:59:59' AND '07/01/2013 00:00:01' 
           THEN 1 END) AS IssuesOpened, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN ResolvedDate BETWEEN '06/30/2012 23:59:59' AND '07/01/2013 00:00:01' 
           THEN 1 END) AS IssuesClosed
FROM Users u
    INNER JOIN Issues i ON 
         i.CreatedByUserID = u.UserID OR i.ResolvedByUserID = u.UserID
WHERE i.DateCreated BETWEEN '06/30/2012 23:59:59' AND '07/01/2013 00:00:01'
    OR ResolvedDate BETWEEN '06/30/2012 23:59:59' AND '07/01/2013 00:00:01'
GROUP BY LastName, FirstName
```

BTW -- when dealing with date fields, I would suggest using >= and < accordingly instead of `BETWEEN`.

Comment: Why don't you like BETWEEN?

Comment: @Goat_CO -- take a look at this article for some good reasons: https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: Oh, you meant when dealing with DATETIME fields, not DATE fields. I'm not compelled by that article, if we were limited to using functions that didn't confuse some people we wouldn't be using much of anything.

Comment: @sgeddes When running your latest query, the 2nd one, I get different values for the users than if I ran the queries individually.  For instance, for the User 'Andrew', your query returns 317 opened and 347 closed, yet when I run the individual queries, I get 147 opened and 291 closed.  I will try to get a SQLFiddle going to see if that helps any.

Comment: @Robert -- any luck with the fiddle?  This looks like it should work unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @sgeddes Unfortunately, no....there appears to be a limit on the Schema size to 8000 characters so I can't insert any of my data once I get the schema built.....ugh.

Answer (score 0):

I would go about it like this:

1. Unpivot all the `Issue` data for the specified period so that every row contains just a user ID and a status change that the user has caused (`'Opened'` or `'Closed'`).
2. Pivot the result set counting the status changes for every user ID.
3. Join the pivoted set to `Users` to access the names.

This is what I've come up with in the course of implementing the above:

```
WITH unpivoted AS (
  SELECT
    x.UserID,
    x.IssueStatusChange
  FROM Issues
  CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES
      (CreatedByUserID,  'Opened', DateCreated),
      (ResolvedByUserID, 'Closed', ResolvedDate)
  ) x (UserID, IssueStatusChange, ChangeDate)
  WHERE x.ChangeDate BETWEEN '06/30/2012 23:59:59'
                         AND '07/01/2013 00:00:01'
),
pivoted AS (
  SELECT
    UserID,
    Opened,
    Closed
  FROM unpivoted
  PIVOT (COUNT(IssueStatusChange)
  FOR IssueStatusChange IN (Opened, Closed)) p
),
SELECT
  UserName = u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName,
  p.Opened,
  p.Closed
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN pivoted p ON u.UserID = p.UserID
;
```

If someone's interested, there's also a [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a30c/2) for this query, albeit the testing datasets aren't very remarkable (probably OK to see the thing in work, though).